# How to create a test directory in Intellij 13?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm an Intellij noob using v13.

I have a simple java project (default) structure that looks like:

```
  [] .idea
  [] src
     [] com.test
          mytestClass1
          mytestClass2
```

Now, I want to write a simple test and I'd like to put that code in  /src/test/java directory.  So I decided to change my project format so that it looks like:

```
 [] .idea
   [] src
     [] main
        [] java    
        [] resources
     [] test
        [] java    
        [] resources
```

After I create that structure, I'd obviously like to move my current classes in src to the main/java/com...  structure.

I've read all about [content roots and project structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html).  The info even states, "Folders within content roots can be assigned to the following categories: sources, test sources, generated sources, generated test sources and excluded folders (in Java modules - also resources and test resources)"

I've tried right-clicking on the project name then New -> Directory then entering "src/main/java" (also tried it with a leading slash) but when I right-click my new directory and select "**Mark Directory As**" the only option is **Excluded**.

If I create a new directory in the root, I can select **Mark Directory As Test Sources Root** but it still hangs off the root like:

```
  [] .idea
  [] java
  [] src
     [] com.test
```

Can someone please tell me how to migrate to my desired structure?

Comment: The directories structures for tests and tested classes must fit. Here is how to do it easily: stackoverflow.com/a/36057080/715269

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You should have structure like this one:

```
 [] .idea    
 [] src
    [] main
      [] java   
           com.simpleproject
             SimpleClass.java
      [] resources
    [] test
      [] java
           com.simpleproject
             SimpleClassTest.java
      [] resources
```

After that go to: File->Project Structure->Modules and in "Sources" tab you can choose which folder is "test folder" (usually java in test), which "sources" (usually java in main) etc by clicking "Mark as" options.

Comment: Nice! Worked.  And can you tell me the best way to refactor so that the old classes are in the new structure?  (I tried <rt click>->Refactor->Move but isn't working as I'd hoped.

Comment: I am not sure I understand but I think "drag and drop" package folder/class in project view on the left side of IDE will help :)

Comment: I needed to create the package in the new location before dragging any of the classes or sub packages.  I right-clicked on my new java folder and doing a create -> package.  Then I could drag classes from the old location to the new one without messing up package info.  Moving a sub-package worked then also by choosing "Move everything from .....to another directory" on the Select Refactoring window.  Thanks.

Comment: This still seems to be the correct procedure for IntelliJ 14. Why is it so complicated? Is it because IntelliJ normally adds the test sources root on project creation?

Comment: It needn't be so complicated. Look here: stackoverflow.com/a/36057080/715269

Comment: This does not work. `java` is a "prohibited package name".

Comment: Works after setting `sources` to `java` instead of `main`.

Comment: I am always unclear on one detail. In this example is com.simpleproject a package name in the classes or a folder under java (or scala) in the project?