# How to create a separate test-directory in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I have the following project structure:

[image]

I want to create tests in the "tests"-folder in the bottom. When I copy-paste a test class inside, it is obviously not recognized, as seen in the image below. 
How should I make Android Studio recognize the "tests" directory, or something inside it, as a test folder?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What isn't recognized? What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Since AndroidStudio is IntelliJ based, I think that you should be able to mark your folder as a test folder in the same way you would mark a test folder in IntelliJ (i.e. File->Project Structure->Modules and choosing your given folder as a test folder). See [this answer which described it for IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161314/4851565).

Comment: You'd actually use Gradle to establish that, not use the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You should place your tests within the actual modules

This is how the Android + Java Gradle modules work by default.

```
android
  src 
    main
      java
    test
      java
    androidTest
      java
core
  src
    main
      java
    test 
      java
```

If you want "integration test", make a new module for that and `compile()` each module, then still follow that directory structure.

You may find info at [**Getting Started with Testing**](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html)