# Importing testng classes when scope marked 'test'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, pom.xml

I have a testng dependency in pom.xml with 'test' scope:

```
</dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My folder layout is as follows:

```
src/test/java  - test source folder
src/test/resources - test resources folder
```

When trying to import testng in classes created under src/test/java/ IntelliJ can not find testng.

Comment: show us the exception

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161314/5074444

Comment: I think his source sets are correct. It might be IntelliJ project structure, as far as I remember IntelliJ marks sources differently by default.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven#174670

Comment: @LazerBanana, I'm getting an error from IntelliJ, not exception when running. I.e. enter @Test annotation in my code and the autocomplete only shows JUnit @Test annotation, and TestNG is ommited. If I manually enter `import org.testng.annotations.Test;` then IntelliJ tells - Can not resolve symbol Test.

Answer (score 1):

First of all open `Maven Projects` tab and simply refresh to get in sync.

Secondly, open the `project structure` and check if your sources are marked correctly.

Without more info, this is what I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have src/test/java in one module/project and you would like to reuse it in other module/project? If that's correct you need to build and install your test jar (add to your source project):

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>

           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>test-jar</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you can use it in other projects by adding maven dependency.