# Can't find persistence.xml and provider while both specified

Tags: java, hibernate

When I am running my unit test I these two errors

> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser doResolve
>   INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

and

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named dbContext

I don't get them both because as you can see in the image en persistence.xml file below this text everything is there that he is complaining about.

[image: FolderStructure]

and here you have my persistance.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dbContext">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="{urltodb}"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="{myusername}"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="{mypassword}"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be in `src/main/resources/META-INF`?

Comment: It is. Intellij just diplays that different and i have no clue why. But when i hover over the persistence file it states that it is in the scr/main/resources/META-INF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder structure is completely mixed up:

1. Your `src`-Folder is marked as source-folder (blue), so the subfolder main is interpreted as Java-Package
2. Your resources-folder is within your `sources/main`-folder That's why Intellij interprets it as package `main.resources.META-INF`.
3. (All your real packages start with upper-case. That's not an error, but unusual nevertheless)

How your folder structure should look like:

- src/main/java => Mark this as source folder and put all your java packages there
- src/main/resources => Mark this as resources folder an put your META-INF there

See also: [How to create a test directory in Intellij 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160379/how-to-create-a-test-directory-in-intellij-13/28161314#28161314)